# No se encuentra el include path

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Estoy intentando compilar un proyecto en C++ en el que utilizo algunas librerias, todo andaba perfectamente hasta que de repente el compilador comenzó a decir que no encontraba el archivo de la librería.

Tengo configurado en el proyecto los, Aditional Include Paths correctamente sin embargo no encuentra los archivos. Solo funciona si en la directiva Include pongo el path absoluto al archivo, ni siquiera si pongo el path absoluto a la carpeta de la librería bajo Aditional includes anda.

Intellisense encuentra los archivos pero el compilador no.

Ya llevo horas intentando solucionarlo y nada de lo que encontré en internet funcionó.

Estoy usando Visual Studio 2017 con su compilador.

Mis archivos (headers y source files) están bajo:

```
SolutionDir/ProjectDir/GameStudio/src/
```

Y las librerías están bajo:

```
SolutionDir/ProjectDir/GameStudio/vendor/(Nombre de la Librería)/
```

Los Aditional Include Paths son

> $(ProjectDir)vendor

He intentado tanto usando `< >`

```
#include <(Nombre de la Librería)/archivo.h>
```

como usando `" "`

```
#include "(Nombre de la Librería)/archivo.h"
```

y también cambie los archivos de carpeta pero nada de esto funcionó.

Comment: @Trauma Lo siento, ya actualize la información.

Comment: @Trauma Si, ya probé poniendo las comillas en vez de los angular brackets, pero no funcionó. También intente usar las barras / y \\ así al especificar el directorio pero ninguna sirvió.

Comment: Qué pasa si en los Include paths pones la ruta completa hacia vendor, en lugar de $(ProjectDir)vendor?